# Using bean value in java

Tags: java, struts

I have defined a bean

```
<logic:iterate id="keyRecDetail" name="KeyRecInquiryForm" property="keyRecDetailList" indexId="rowNum">
```

Now i want to access value of ${keyRecDetail.keyRecShipMethod} in my jsp page and put this value in a string.how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:-**

**Declare**

```
<jsp:useBean id="emp" class="bean.Employees"/>
```

**Get the property**

```
<jsp:getProperty name="emp" property="firstName"/>
```